# c# Form in Class start thread

Tags: multithreading

one class sample : testHTTP.class in this code

```
        public String httptest(object httptestx)
        {
         var data = (Tuple<string, string, string>)httptestx;
         var s = data.Item1;
         var k = data.Item2;
         var p = data.Item3;        
         ............................

        }
```

Form1 thread class not start please help me ... :

```
   private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                for (Int32 i5 = 0; i5 < textBox5.Lines.Length; i5++)
                {
                    var thr1 = new Thread(dfproJesiHttpClass.httptest());
                    var data = new Tuple<string, string, string>(textBox6.Lines[i6].Trim(), textBox4.Lines[i4].Trim(), textBox5.Lines[i5].Trim());
                    thr1.Start(data);
                    threads.Add(thr1);
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd be surprised if that code compiles. You need to change this line:

```
var thr1 = new Thread(dfproJesiHttpClass.httptest());
```

to

```
var thr1 = new Thread(dfproJesiHttpClass.httptest);
```

Assuming that `dfproJesiHttpClass` is an instance and not the name of the class.